# Oracle SQL: ON Clause

Tags: sql, oracle

```
SELECT e.employee_id, e.last_name, d.department_id, d.location_id
FROM employees e JOIN departments d
ON (e.department_id=d.department_id);
```

What exactly does the ON clause do? I'm confused on why e.department_id and d.department_id doesn't cause an error? Doesn't e represent the employees table and d represent the department table? So how can you use e.department_id if department_id is not in the employees table? I'm extremely confused about the purpose of the ON clause.

Comment: `ON` is a part of `JOIN` clause

Comment: What do you mean by department_id is not in the employees table?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `ON` clause is part of the `JOIN` syntax and it is used to identify how the tables should be joined to each other, in other words what columns relate the tables to each other.

In your case you are joining the tables on the `e.department_id` and the `d.department_id`.

The `e` is the alias for `employees` table and the `d` is the alias for the `departments` table.

Your current query is performing an `INNER JOIN` which will return only those rows that are matching in both tables.

If you want to return all `employees` even if there is no `departments` associated with an employee row, then you will want to use a `LEFT JOIN`:

```
SELECT e.employee_id, e.last_name, d.department_id, d.location_id
FROM employees e 
LEFT JOIN departments d
  ON e.department_id=d.department_id;
```

Comment: I'm still confused about what the ON (e.department_id=d.department_id) does? I understand that the ON relates them, but how? department_id is not a column in the employees table (e), so how is it relating them?

Comment: @KG The `employees` table has a column called `department_id` and so does the `departments` table. The `ON` is specifying what columns the tables are being joined on. Basically it states that you want to return the rows that the `department_id` matches in the two tables.

Comment: `department_id` **is** a column in the `employees` table (`e`), but it is not in the returned results (you haven't out it in the `SELECT` list.) You can always add it and see.

Comment: Oh. Sorry. I didn't see the department_id table in the employees table. Thanks!

Comment: @KG can you post the definitions for the `employees` and `departments` tables? You're saying that (a) `Employees` doesn't have a `department_id` column and (b) the query runs without error. That doesn't sound right, which is why the comments are getting increasingly skeptical.

Comment: @KG glad you figured it out! :)

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if it helps you to understand, but it's possible (though not recommended) to re-write this very query with implicit inner join in a form of `WHERE` clause:

```
SELECT e.employee_id, e.last_name, d.department_id, d.location_id
FROM employees e, departments d
WHERE (e.department_id=d.department_id);
```

Comment: Why isn't it recommended to do as you say? I'd love to know.

Comment: @Phil - I've been told that explicit JOINs (especially when they are many of them) are easier to read and maintain.  I did not imply that it impacts performance.

Comment: I find it easier to read when it's all in the `WHERE` clause, but that is my personal preference. In fact, being an Oracle question, this is the norm for Oracle as `.. JOIN ..` was only introduced relatively recently. "though not recommended" was entirely your personal preference and should therefore not be stated in an answer.

Comment: Phil - `JOIN` is a part of a standard now and the fact, that Oracle had its own `(+)` syntax before and still has it now,  is not *that* material for the advise I provided.  You obviously can keep your opinion.